# Format cell for comma-separated values

Tags: string, excel, vba

Written a VBA script which outputs numbers and I thought I had the correct format string for thousand-separating (4,656,565  5,343   232,434 etc) but its not working for certain magnitudes of numbers.

So far I am using `Cells(x,y).NumberFormat = "#,###"`

can someone provide me with the correct format string to thousand-comma-separate any number, no matter the magnitude?

Comment: I tried "#,##0" for non decimal and it works. Can you give us an example where it is not working?

Comment: It worked for 4,xxx,xxx but it didnt work for 8xx,xxx or 45,xxx,xxx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works for me. Notice, formatting the cell first before assigning the number to it

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    With Cells(1, 1)
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
        .Value = 4.65656553432324E+16 '46565655343232400
    End With
End Sub
```

**RESULT**

Cell A1 has `46,565,655,343,232,400`